# Suppress cursor.execute() message in python MySQLdb

Tags: python, cursor, mysql-python

How to suppress the cursor.execute() message in MySQLdb.

```
>>> from warnings import filterwarnings
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> filterwarnings('ignore', category = MySQLdb.Warning)
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '','')
>>> cursor = db.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("select version()")
1L
```

I need to suppress this '1L' message

Comment: That's not a message, that's the *return value*.

Comment: @martin, Thanks. Can I suppress this value?

Comment: assign it to a variable? Why do you need to surpress it?

Comment: I am looping through a text file and inserting each record in the mysql table. For each cursor.execute(), I am getting this value, which is annoying in my case. But assigning to a variable may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you see there is not a warning message, but the return value of `cursor.execute()`. It's the number of rows affected, 1.

The API happens to return a Python [`long` integer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex), but it's otherwise the same as a regular `int` value:

```
>>> 1L
1L
>>> 1
1
>>> 1 == 1L
True
```

If you do not want the Python console to echo return values back to you, assign them to a variable:

```
>>> somevariable = 1L
```